# Dynamo connected to ceiling fan to charge a battery

Tags: voltage, current, motor, generator, dynamo

Just a hypothetical scenario :

I am thinking of connecting a dynamo to the ceiling fan to charge up a battery which might be later used to power some low power gadgets. Whether this would save my electricity as I charging a battery from an already running device (ceiling fan) and later using this energy to power some other gadget which would otherwise require electricity directly.

Can someone guide me whether it is possible to save electricity by this method? If not, why?

Comment: Won't save electricity, but sounds like a fun project.

Comment: Actually, it will save electricity in the sense that you were probably going to run the fan anyway, and you probably won't notice that the dynamo is slowing down the moving air. But from a thermodynamics perspective, no, it won't save energy compared to NOT running the fan and just charging the battery directly.

Comment: At best, It'll make the fan consume the energy the battery charger would...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By the law of conservation of energy you can not get more energy out of a system, as you put in. So the answer is no.

You put energy into your fan to make it spin, then draw energy from it to run a dynamo to charge a battery. So either you have to put more energy into the fan to drive the dynamo, or simply your fan runs slower and less efficient due to friction.

It's the same, when you power your bike light with a dynamo. You have to pedal harder (put more energy into the bike) to reach the same speed, when your dynamo is connected and your light turned on, as those draw energy out of the system, which would otherwise result in more speed.

Why not plug the battery directly into the wall outlet? No spinning fan, no air moved, no spinning dynamo, no friction produced, no losses in converting the energy.

If you could save energy like that, everybody would do it.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: no ;)

Any energy you get from the fan must come from somewhere. This includes a minuscule amount of energy stored as momentum which you can extract by stopping the fan. All the rest must come from the fan's electrical connection, and even that momentum was provided by the electrical connection in the first place.

All these conversion steps (dynamo, battery) have losses which waste some (actually quite a lot) of the energy as heat.

So you'll be better off charging your devices directly!

Answer (score 0):

It will be more energy cost-effective and energy efficient to use an AC battery charger to charge your battery.

When you charge a battery you use power and that power has to come from somewhere (i.e. it is not free) so, the most economical method of obtaining that power is clearly going to be the winner. Attaching a dynamo to a fan extracts power from that fan whenever that fan is turning. That power comes from your AC supply and you are billed for it.

Dynamos are nothing like 100% power efficient and neither is your ceiling fan so, it makes no sense to do this unless you have no other option. A properly designed battery charger will be more energy efficient and hence cheaper on bills.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Just asking, what would be the effect if the dynamo is connected to the ceiling fan? could you explain

Comment: @Newbie over time, your energy bills would be slightly higher.

Answer (score 0):

Everyone is saying "no" and they are technically correct. Because if your goal is to charge a battery, there is no point in running the fan. Just charge the battery directly from the wall socket. And it is true that in order to charge a battery with an impeller, you have to slow down the air. But realistically, it may be possible to do what you want, and the resulting slowdown of the air moved by the fan may not be noticeable. Also, I don't think the fan motor will "feel" any increase in load due to the presence of the impeller downstream.

Comment: My goal is to charge the battery at the same time, having the fan produce the same air circulation as it would do when it is not connected to the dynamo. In that case, the fan motor has to spin more right so as to charge the battery as well as provide the actual circulation?